# Разворачивание ссылок на вопросы сети

Tags: предложение

Посмотрим на такую разметку:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434183/178988  
https://stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642
```

[Запуск глобальных модулей nodejs из кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434183/178988)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642

Как видно, ссылка с этого сайта отображается в виде заголовка вопроса, а с другого сайта сети - так и остаётся ссылкой. Приходится руками проописывать

```
[How to start a globally installed module as an an application frome the code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642)
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы ссылки на другие сайты тоже сами отображались как заголовок вопроса.

---

И ещё один момент - в ссылке, которая прописана явно, можно не указывать протокол, чтобы переход осуществлялся по тому же протоколу, который используется в данный момент:

```
[Some question](//stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642)
```

Хотелось бы такую фичу для ссылок на сайты сети. Например, игнорировать указанный протокол при формировании ссылки на ресурс в сети SE.

Comment: Тогда уже чтобы можно было как на Хэшкоде: [Разворачивание ссылок на вопросы сети](/q/2522/).

Comment: Хм, сработало, не знал :) `[Разворачивание ссылок на вопросы сети](/q/2522/)`.

Comment: @VladD, это фишка ссылок, а не движка. И вообще, [несколько фич форматирования](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316084/4928642)

Comment: Ну, парсер ещё должен по идее распарсить это как валидную ссылку. Или он тупой и подставляет как есть? Тогда у нас напрашивается XSS :-)